# How can I make the text wrap around the image in this scenario?

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

https://codepen.io/hjklhjklhjkl/pen/zYmdmje

The following code:

```css
.image {
    border-radius: 20%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom:0.5cm;
    margin-top:0.5cm;
    width: 50%;
}

.image-container img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px
}

.left {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 20px 20px 0;
   }

.navbar{
    padding:15px
}

  .jumbotron{
    background-color:skyblue;
    padding: 30px
  }

.container {
    padding:20px;
}


/*
  .image.active {
    opacity: 1;
  }*/


  @media (min-width: 600px) {
    .image {
        border-radius: 20%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom:0.5cm;
    margin-top:0.5cm;
    width: 20%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;

    }

    .image-container img {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px
    }
  }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!--Make it unsearcheable! (for now :))-->
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0a48c3a8e0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      </head>
      <!-- Nav Bar -->
      <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark sticky-top" style="background-color: steelblue;">
          <a class="navbar-brand text-center" href="#about">asdf</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#interests">Interests</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="dynamic-container">
          <!-- Jumbotron -->
          <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid text-center jumbotron-blue">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 image-container">
                  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x400" class="image">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <h2 class="jumbotron-heading">asdf</h2>
                  <p class="text-muted">asdf</p>
                  <a href="files/CurriculumVitaeKopie.pdf">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">asdf</button>
                  </a>
                  <a href="files/Artistic Resume Kopie.pdf">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">asdf</button>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <script src="script.js"></script>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--ABOUT-->
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-14">
                <a id="about" style="position: relative;top: -60px;display: block;height: 0;overflow: hidden;"></a>
                <h1>About</h1>
                <p> asdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlkasdfghjlk </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

So I WANT the image to expand as the screen expands. However, I want the text to move to wrap around the image... I have tried so many combinations of wrapping off the paragraph and letting the image float, but it doesn't work! Why? It was always worked previously for me